# Convert bytes to binary

Tags: php, random, binary, byte

I'm using this function https://php.net/random_bytes
and i would to convert this random bytes to a binary view.

I've tried to convert it to hex2bin and then i used to function pack to convert it to a binary but it doesn't work.

How can convert a random bytes to a binary ?

Comment: I guess `random_bytes` returns a binary string.. You can use `bin2hex()` instead to show hex values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random_bytes` returns binary data, but not in a readable format. If you want to actually represent it as a string of 1s and 0s, you'll need to first convert it using one of PHP's `bin2*` functions, then use `base_convert` to convert it back:

```
<?php
function random_binary($bytes) {
  return base_convert(bin2hex(random_bytes($bytes)), 16, 2);
}

echo random_binary(1);

// 10000011
```

This will only work up to the system's integer limit (likely 2^63-1 on a 64-bit system). If you've got the [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extension installed, you can use the following for arbitrary precision:

```
<?php
function random_binary($bytes) {
  $hex = bin2hex(random_bytes($bytes));
  return gmp_strval(gmp_init($hex, 16), 2);
}

echo random_binary(40);

// 10000000101110000010011111001011011100111110...
```

Comment: Why sometimes the binary is only  0 ?
string(40) "e1b813b168a91d6bffd1022c7c998e7ace328240"
string(64) "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

Comment: That is because of floating point precision, the the warning in the doc of base_convert: http://php.net/base_convert

Comment: base_convert will only work up to your system's integer limit, so likely just under 8 bytes (2^63 - 1). I've added another solution, although it's dependent on the GMP extension.